# jQuery: how to add an active class to a navigation link if I need the same link to be highlighted on multiple pages?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, categories

I have something like a category structure, where 3 pages fall under one category, and I want to highlight a link for that category on all three pages.

I would be thankful if you can suggest a way to do this with jQuery.
I've only found solutions for this via href, for when one link corresponds to one page.

Edit:

Sorry, I guess I should've posted the code right away.

```
<div class="left">
/.../
<ul>
<li><a href="paolini.html">Marinella Paolini, Urban Soul</a></li>
<li><a href="scaccia.html">Beatrice Scaccia and Marta Jovanovic</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="right">
<h3>Marinella Paolini, URBAN SOUL</h3>
<p>November 23, 2011 - January 15, 2012</p>

<ul class="galMenu">
<li><a href="#" class="act">IMAGES</a></li>
<li><a href="paolini-press.html">PRESS RELEASE</a></li>
<li><a href="paolini-aboutartist.html">ARTIST</a></li>
</ul>
/.../
</div>
```

I need a way to check which artist is it, either by checking the contents of h3, or by checking the url of the page (a part of it), then find the corresponding link in the #left ul and highlight it.
Is there any way to do that?

Edit2:

Ok, I managed to come up with:

```
var $artist = $('h3').text();           
if ($("#left ul li a:contains($artist)")) {
$(this).addClass("active");
}
```

If I put '#left ul li a' instead of 'this', it adds the active class to all the links, but it does nothing if I leave 'this'. How do I get it to add the class only to the link that contains the variable?

I know I'm fumbling here. I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Can you please describe this in more detail?  Highlighting a link is simple to do with jQuery, but I suspect you want to do something a little trickier than that.

Comment: Ok, I have a ul with links for 5 artists, and then for each of those artists I have a submenu for an image gallery page, press release page and a bio page. I need code that would highlight a link in the main navigation (the artist's name) in all three of those pages automatically.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of highlighting a link that has the same text as h2 or something, but I don't know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/kUeXd/

I did it using one main id and one class to define the active element because I do not know what is your structure of menu. You should get the idea of how to do it based on the example and implement it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
var artist = $('h3').text();
$("#left ul li a:contains('" + artist + "')").addClass('active');
```